# return array of objects based on object of keywords

Tags: javascript

I have this object containing data for each keyword:

```
const a = {
  word1: { mains: [ 5 ], secondaries: [1, 22, 50] },
  word2: { mains: [ 5, 66 ], secondaries: [1] },
  word3: { mains: [ 5 ], secondaries: [1] },
}
```

And I want this array of objects containing data of the above object sorted based on `length` of `mains` array and `secondaries` array for each keyword, I mean :

```
mains.length + secondaries.length
```

Here is the desired output:

```
[

  { keyword: 'word3', mains: [ 5 ], secondaries: [1] }, // length of mains and secondaries = 2
  { keyword: 'word2', mains: [ 5, 66 ], secondaries: [1] }, // length of mains and secondaries = 3
  { keyword: 'word1', mains: [ 5 ], secondaries: [1, 22, 50] }, // length of mains and secondaries = 4

]
```

What is the proper solution to achieve such a functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here a "one-liner" solution:

```js
const a = {
  word1: { mains: [5], secondaries: [1, 22, 50] },
  word2: { mains: [5, 66], secondaries: [1] },
  word3: { mains: [5], secondaries: [1] }
}

const result = Object.entries(a).map(
  ([keyword, item]) => ({keyword, ...item})
).sort(
  (a, b) => (a.mains.length + a.secondaries.length) - (b.mains.length + b.secondaries.length)
)

console.log(result);
```

This will first use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to transform `a` object entries into an array of objects with `keyword` property, then [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) this based on the sums of lengths.

Answer (score 3):

simply

```js
const objA = 
  { word1: { mains: [ 5] ,     secondaries: [ 1, 22, 50] } 
  , word2: { mains: [ 5, 66] , secondaries: [ 1]         } 
  , word3: { mains: [ 5] ,     secondaries: [ 1]         } 
  } 

const sumLen = ([_, {mains,secondaries}]) => mains.length + secondaries.length ;
  
const result = Object.entries(objA)
                .sort((a,b)=>sumLen(a)-sumLen(b))
                .map(([keyword,obj])=>({keyword, ...obj}))

console.log( result )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

Comment: No sorting.......

Comment: true, @SaraRee  so I updated my anwser...

Answer (score 2):

```
const a = {
    word1: { mains: [ 5 ], secondaries: [1, 22, 50] },
    word2: { mains: [ 5, 66 ], secondaries: [1] },
    word3: { mains: [ 5 ], secondaries: [1] },
};

let array = [];
for (let prop in a) {
    let newProp = {keyword: prop};
    array.push(Object.assign(newProp, a[prop]));
}

array.sort((a, b) => {
    return (a.mains.length + a.secondaries.length) -
            (b.mains.length + b.secondaries.length);
});
```